# Ensuring right data is read from an InputStream

Tags: java, android

I have a root application that is supposed to capture the screen at some point during the execution. In order to accomplish this, I interact with the Android shell using the following code:

```
private static Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
private static DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
private static DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(su.getInputStream());

private void CaptureScreen() {
    outputStream.writeBytes("/system/bin/screencap -p\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    //outputStream.writeBytes("echo test\n");
    //outputStream.flush();
}
```

It works fine, even when I call it multiple times, but the moment I issue a dummy command that produces a shell output between CaptureScreen calls, BitmapFactory.decodeStream fails. Considering this, I have a few questions:

- I assume this happens because the data within the InputStream is no
  longer purely related to image data. Since the runtime is single
  instance (as referred to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime())), I again assume that other
  processes can also introduce their outputs within my InputStream on a
  live system. How can I make sure to only get the data I need from the
  InputStream?
- Why does CaptureScreen work correctly when called multiple times? How
  does BitmapFactory.decodeStream manage to get the last image from the
  InputStream? Does it "consume" relevant data when it succeeds? Does
  it search for the last image data from the InputStream? If so, why does it
  fail when there is irrelevant data before the image data within the
  InputStream?

I know I can get around this problem by writing the image to a file then read it from there, but I would like to avoid I/O operations in favor of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After toying around with this for a while, I found the answer to my own questions:

- Although the runtime is single instance, executing a code on it starts a new process on its own. Input and output streams related to this process can only be written/read by this process (unless another process specifically redirects its streams to this process, which is extremely unlikely in my case).
- Contents of an input stream are indeed "consumed" upon reading, thus calling this function multiple times writes/reads the image data wholly. "Polluting" the input stream of the process with data not related to the image breaks decodeStream's functionality.

Also keep in mind that "su" isn't a command that *ends*. It does not terminate until called to do so. Here's the revised class I use in my code:

```
public class BitmapScreencap {
    public final static BitmapScreencap Get = new BitmapScreencap();
    private BitmapScreencap() { }
    public Bitmap Screen() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.write("/system/bin/screencap -p\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(process.getInputStream());
            outputStream.write("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return screen;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And it can be called from anywhere within your project as:

```
BitmapScreencap.Get.Screen();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure to only get the data I need from the InputStream?

At least you can check exitValue of the Process

> Why does CaptureScreen work correctly when called multiple times?

It simply reads stream until gets -1 as result of read. When you send "/system/bin/screencap -p\n" to process, InputStream starts to return new data again.