# ScreenCap directly toByteArray , skipping saving to memory

Tags: java, android, arrays, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to optimise the code below , would it be possible to directly ScreenCap to Byte Array so I can skip the step of saving it into memory.

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/colorPickerTemp.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/colorPickerTemp.png");//You can get an inputStream using any IO API
byte[] bytes;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
int bytesRead;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
bytes = output.toByteArray();
final String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313412/android-screencap-to-bytes-directly-skip-saving-to-file ?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Bitmap is Bytes? I cant seem to find a way to send that Bitmap over HTTP or Base64 it

Comment: Yes, you can easily convert `Bitmap` to `byte[]`

Comment: So link is only example. You can directly put process' output to bytearray.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rainbowhat/c5c43cbe6fa89e546f47021bff0a3b99 Not sure how , still trying to figure this out

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Screencap usage](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/2e9e624c76f5710e24b23d4378f22086ce0a8610/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp#L54):

> "usage: %s [-hp] [-d display-id] [FILENAME]\n"
>       " -h: this message\n"
>       " -p: save the file as a png.\n"
>       " -d: specify the display id to capture, default %d.\n"
>       "If FILENAME ends with .png it will be saved as a png.\n"
>       "If FILENAME is not given, the results will be printed to stdout.\n"

So you can do something like this:

```
public String getScreenshotBase64() throws IOException {
    return Base64.encodeToString(getScreenshotImageBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

public byte[] getScreenshotImageBytes() throws IOException {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.write("/system/bin/screencap -p\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    byte[] bytes = readBytes(process.getInputStream());
    outputStream.write("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    return bytes;
}

public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  int bufferSize = 1024;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

  int len = 0;
  while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
  }

  return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: I seem to be having issue running this inside a Service. If you could advice.

Comment: I/art: Thread[2,tid=24999,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb3c27c00,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

Comment: App isn't responding. Do you want to close it , I get this after that text appear

Comment: @CodeGuru wait a minute.

Comment: @CodeGuru I have your problem too. So google says that maybe root rights received in an unsuitable way. I don't know how to solve this problem but I will try again later.